# Check if inputted zip-code match credit-card's zip code

Tags: php, credit-card, authorize.net

I'm writing a web form which let user input their zip code and credit card number, then check if the zip code they inputted match the zip code stored in the card's information. I don't think I can push card number on authorize.net api, they will let me have the information.

But what if I push both number and the zip code, is it possible to have them let me know if the zip code matched?

Comment: Well, check their documentation, I'd say!

Comment: It seems there is a validation active already. https://www.authorize.net/support/CNP/helpfiles/Account/Settings/Security_Settings/Fraud_Settings/Address_Verification_System_%28AVS%29.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done manually as you cannot get bank access. However [this](https://www.authorize.net/support/CNP/helpfiles/Account/Settings/Security_Settings/Fraud_Settings/Address_Verification_System_%28AVS%29.htm) might help :)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot programmitcally do this as that information is only verifiable from the card issuing bank. So to do this you need to use the [Address Verification System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Verification_System) (AVS).

To do this you must run either a $0.00 `AUTH_ONLY` transaction, or if the processing bank does not support that run a $0.01 `AUTH_ONLY` and then a `VOID` to undo that transaction. You will then receive an AVS result which you can use to the if the provided value from correct. (You cal also process your `AUTH_CAPTURE` transaction normally and then upon a failed response `VOID` the transaction).

These are the possible response values:

```
B    Address information was not submitted in the transaction information, so AVS check could not be performed
E    The AVS data provided is invalid, or AVS is not allowed for the card type submitted
R    AVS was unavailable at the time the transaction was processed. Retry transaction
G    The credit card issuing bank is of non-U.S. origin and does not support AVS
U    Address information is not available for the customer's credit card
S    The U.S. card issuing bank does not support AVS
N    Neither the street address nor the 5-digit ZIP code matches the address and ZIP code on file for the card
A    The street address matches, but the 5-digit ZIP code does not
Z    The first 5 digits of the ZIP code matches, but the street address does not match
W    The 9-digit ZIP code matches, but the street address does not match
Y    The street address and the first 5 digits of the ZIP code match perfectly
```

Keep in mind that AVS generally only works in the United States.

Also, a failed AVS response does *not* mean the credit card is stolen or the transaction is fraudulent. It just means *the user entered a different zip code than is on the billing address for that credit card*. Many people have a different home address then billing address and commonly enter the zip of their home rather than the billing address of the card. It is *not* recommended that you reject transactions based on a failed AVS response. It should be one of *several* tools you use which includes CVV and other tools.